# Prometheus (node_exporter) issue when update from GKE 1.15 to 1.16

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus-node-exporter

I'm using Prometheus and Grafana applications on Kubernetes in Google GKE since many months. For example, on Grafana I used to monitor `container_cpu_usage_seconds_total`.

But since I upgraded my nodes of GKE from 1.15 to 1.16, I have lost `container_*` information.

To test it, I have created a new cluster with the 1.15 version. I installed Prometheus from the Google Marketeplace and upgraded GKE step by step until the issue appears. Again, the `container_*` monitoring stopped with version 1.16.

[Here you can see `container_cpu_usage_seconds_total` and it stopped when I upgrade the node. There are 3 nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9aF0.png)

Am I the only one with this issue? Has anyone found a solution?

Thanks for your help :)

Valentin

Comment: Did you check for logs in prometheus/grafana containers?

Comment: In node_exporter, i have this :

`2020-09-08T09:35:26.426156249Z time="2020-09-08T09:35:26Z" level=error msg="ERROR: diskstats collector failed after 0.100237s: invalid line for /host/proc/diskstats for sdl" source="collector.go:123"`

In prometheus i have this:

`level=warn ts=2020-09-08T09:32:12.538Z caller=klog.go:86 component=k8s_client_runtime func=Warningf msg="/app/discovery/kubernetes/kubernetes.go:263: watch of *v1.Endpoints ended with: too old resource version: 183350035 (183351611)"`

Comment: Could you please share the exact version of GKE cluster you are using, and what is the exact application of GCP markeplace you are using?

Comment: GKE cluster : 1.16.13-gke.400
Application in markeplace : Prometheus & Grafana (v2.2) (node_exporter: v0.15.2 ; prometheus: 2.11.0)
Thanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what was going wrong.
With docker or kubernetes, node-exporter don't send pods metrics ( `container_*` ).
Cadvisor must be installed (In Google Marketeplace, Cadvisor is installed in node-exporter image)
Since Kubernetes 1.16, Cadvisor's configuration is wrong. You should edit the configuration to solve the issue

All informations are in this post : [Prometheus not receiving metrics from cadvisor in GKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63691208/prometheus-not-receiving-metrics-from-cadvisor-in-gke)